# Laravel Joins to retrieve total count

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, eloquent, eager-loading

I have been trying to figure it out with documentation and many tries but I can't get through this quite simple problem. I'm using Laravel 7.

I have 3 tables.

*Relations between models are set like Training hasMany Episodes. And my completions table has user_id, episode_id because it is a many to many relation to show which episode has been watched by users.*

**Trainings table : id, title, description**

**Episodes table : id, title, episode_number, description, video_url, training_id (foreign_key)**

**Completions table : id, user_id, episode_id**

In my index view, I foreach every training, and I'd like to show how many users has watched at least 1 episode. I tried to eager-load the episodes table of a training, then I want to join the completions table, then I want to GROUP BY user_id and count them but it doesn't work at all... A little help please? :)

The code I tried :

```
$trainings = Training::with('user')->with(['episodes' => function ($query) {
    $query->join('completions', 'episodes.id', '=', 'completions.episode_id')
        ->join('users', 'completions.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('completions.*, episodes.*', DB::raw('COUNT(completions.user_id) as totalctn'))
        ->groupBy('completions.user_id');
    }])->latest()->get();
```

Thanks a lot for reading / helping me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**

Total no of users started training (1 or more episodes under a training).
Something like this would work in mysql I guess, do please try.

```
$userCount = User::select(DB::raw('count(distinct(user_id))'))
 ->join('completions', 'completions.user_id', 'users.id')
 ->join('episodes', 'completions.episode_id', 'episodes.id')
 ->whereColumn('trainings.id', 'episodes.training_id')
 ->toSql(); //get the raw sql to use below

$trainings = Training::with('episodes')
    ->select('trainings.*', 
      DB::raw( "($userCount) as user_count"  ) //insert above sql. take note of the parentheses, it's important since it's actually enclosing the entire sql statement from above
     )
    ->get();
```

Laravel actually uses a similar method behind the `withCount` method.
What's happening here:

- `->select('trainings.*',` this is a normal select that's asking to select all columns of the trainings table
- `DB::raw( "($userCount) as user_count"  )` the `$userCount` will give us the SQL to count the unique user_ids that appears in completions table. The final result of this query will be just the count, so we are attaching that `subquery` as a column called `user_count` into the select list.

  `//in case the subquery needs a basic explanation.`
- `$userCount` query: the important condition here is the condition in `whereColumn`. This is what makes this query attach to every row in the trainings table being selected. So what this query is basically translating to: for each row in trainings table, get all related episode and count the unique user ids. And this gives the no of unique users who has at least one episode in the completions list for a particular training.

---

**UPDATE**

> For every training, I'd like to show how many users has watched at least 1 episode.

```
Training::with(['episodes' => function($query){
  return $query->withCount('users');
}])->get();
```

Now Episode relation will have an attribute named 'users_count', or along those words, that indicates the number of users who have watched the episode.

---

BEFORE UPDATE

> And my completions table has user_id, episode_id because it is a many
> to many relation to show which episode has been watched by users.

Therefore, it is safe to assume that your User model has a belongsToMany relationship method that links User and Episodes through the completions table. Something similar to this:

```
public function completedEpisodes(){
 return $this->belongsToMany(Episode::class, 'completions_table');
}
```

> I'd like to show how many users has watched at least 1 episode.

Now, you can count all users with at least one `completedEpisode` like so:

```
User::has('completedEpisode')->count(); //use get() instead of count if you want to retrieve the results
```

Comment: Thanks for reply ! The User model already had the function with the custom belongsToMany, I'd like to fetch the count grouped by user_id from episodes in my eager-loaded episodes (from trainings). My query always fails... I thought it was a simple join query with count + groupBy but nope...

Comment: So essentially getting the number of episodes a user has completed watching? Or do you want the number of times a user has watched the video related to the Training?

Comment: I'm sorry I must have poorly expressed :( I'd like to get the number of users who watched at least one episode for each training :) Thank you a lot for answering me !

Comment: Oh I seem to have missed 'for every training' my bad. Let me update the answer. I hope I understood you this time lol

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, it actually works but i'd like the count without duplicates and it should stay 1 even if the user has seen the whole training. In a nutshell : the number of participants. That's why I tried to count + groupby in the join query :)

Comment: Hmm.. so you want distinct users from completion table count for a training. Let me think about this. I think you should do a `count(distinct(user_id))`

Comment: It does work perfectly, I was a bit close to find the solution, but I don't understand the way you did it, could you link me some documentation to understand what you exactly did ? Mostly the finale select after the with() :) Thank you very very much ! Please link me documentation =)

Comment: Glad I could help. Actually, I cooked it up from mysql knowledge. You can use subqueries such as this as columns in the select list. Let me try to find a good read you can refer to.

Comment: Actually the documentation looks like a good starting point: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html Check this too: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/subqueries/index.php And I will edit the answer to explain what's happening in that select you mentioned.

Comment: You are awesome <3

Comment: ```$sqlQuery = DB::raw("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id))
        FROM completions
        INNER JOIN episodes ON completions.episode_id = episodes.id
        WHERE trainings.id = episodes.training_id
        ");

        $trainings = Training::with('user')
        ->with('episodes')
        ->select('trainings.*', DB::raw("($sqlQuery) as participants"))
        ->latest()
        ->get();
```
Since I didn't need the users table :) it works perfectly, thank you so much I learned a lot from you dude. Peace

Comment: Yes, now that you mention it, users table join was unnecessary. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```php
DB::raw('some query here')
```

try this:

```php
$trainings = Training::with('user')->with(['episodes' => function ($query) {
    $query->join('completions', 'episodes.id', '=', 'completions.episode_id')
        ->join('users', 'completions.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('completions.*, episodes.*')
        ->groupBy('completions.user_id')
        ->select([DB::raw('COUNT(completions.user_id) as totalctn'),'some','column','you','need']);
    }])->latest()->get();
```

Comment: But i think you can use count function if you make a static call of `Transaction::all()->with(...)->count()`

Comment: Ok dude, thanks a lot for reply ! But I'd like to get the count in my eager-loaded episodes through with(). To do something like $training->episodes->userCount; Something like that. I'll try your code asap and keep in touch :) Do you even think it's possible ?

Comment: yeah i think that is possible you have make 50% of the end of this way i think, but nothing is impossible :) You have make the good choice to join and take relation but i think the select and COUNT as DB::raw can make the job i think.